# Prevent multiple application tabs in Angular

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I am working on an Angular 8 SPA. Because of the way this client application is going to work, it will be very inconvenient for users if multiple tabs running the application can be open at any given time. Is it possible to detect whether or not the application is already running in one tab and if so to close that tab or redirect the route to that already running app?

Sort of like how a Mutex can be used in .NET Framework applications.

Thanks!